# Multiprocessing (Pool) on a function with two arguments

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

So I have a function which does some stuff to several .txt files by taking only two arguments. It is currently working as intended, but I got through something like 10% of my stuff in almost one hour - so it takes some time, since the .txt files are fairly large.

Now, I have then been reading about the package multiprocessing, and especially the Pool segment of this. However, I am not quite sure how I use it properly.

The code I use to run my function is the following:

```
for k, structure in enumerate(structures):
    structure_maker(structure_path, structure)
```

The `structure_path` is always the same, whereas the `structures` is a list of different values, e.g.:

```
structures = [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 25, 27]
```

So how would I go about using the Pool process on this ?
As far as I can read I have to do something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

mypool = Pool(6) # Choosing how many cores I want to use
mypool.map(structure_maker, list)
```

And the `list` is where I get lost. What is that supposed to be ? The `structures` list, and if so, where do I put in my `structure_path` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pool.map()` function works like the built-in `map()` function does, in other words it applies a function passed to it as an argument to the each of the items in an iterable passed to it as a second argument. Each time it calls the supplied function, it provides the next item in the iterable as a *single* argument to the function.

A potential problem in this case is that the function you want to use, `structure_maker()`, requires two arguments. There are different ways around this, but in this case, since one of the arguments is always the same thing, you could use the `functools.partial()` function to create temporary function that only requires the second argument to be passed to it—and you can do it right in the `mypool.map()` call.

Here's what I mean:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def structure_maker(structure_path, structure):
    """ Dummy for testing. """
    return structure_path, structure

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from pprint import pprint
    from functools import partial

    mypool = Pool(4)
    structure_path = 'samething'
    structures = [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 25, 27]
    results = mypool.map(partial(structure_maker, structure_path), structures)
    pprint(results)
```

Output:

```
[('samething', 1),
 ('samething', 3),
 ('samething', 6),
 ('samething', 7),
 ('samething', 8),
 ('samething', 10),
 ('samething', 13),
 ('samething', 25),
 ('samething', 27)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make and unpack a `tuple`.

```
def structure_maker_proxy(args):
    structure_path, structure = args
    structure_maker(structure_path, structure)


from multiprocessing import Pool

mypool = Pool(6) # Choosing how many cores I want to use

lis = [(structure_path, struct) for struct in structures]
mypool.map(structure_maker_proxy, lis)
```